# Database pooling in MongoDB at collection level?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am using database pooling in MongoDB using NodeJS instead of creating a separate client object on every request. Does connection pooling work even at the collection level (if the collection is shared between routes) or is it mandatory to access the collection through the db client object for the connection pooling to work?

For example, consider the code (dbURL doesn't include the db name):

```
        const dbURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
        const client = new MongoClient(dbURL, {
            poolSize: 100
        });

        client.connect((err, db)=>{
            if (err) {
                console.log('ERROR in database connection!');
                reject();
                return;
            }
            const userCollection = db.db('mydb').collection('users);
            //userCollection is shared between routes
        });
```

If the userCollection is shared between various routes, will database pooling still work? Or does it work only at the client level (the object named db in my code)? Will it work at database level ( db.db('mydb') - which returns the actual database) too?

In other words, what is the level at which connection pooling work?

a. client object level

b. database level

c. collection level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is `a. client object`

Image you are going to a store. Having the `client object` is like being at the store already. Switching dbs and collections are similar to choosing which to buy. You are at the store already so there is no cost in choosing what to buy.

---

Here in the [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling) says, as long as you call MongoClient.connect once, you are essentially pooling the db connection already. The mongodb driver handlers the rest of the complexities.

Comment: https://blog.mlab.com/2017/05/mongodb-connection-pooling-for-express-applications/  This tutorial actually uses the database object to do queries and updates. Also the MongoDB University course M220JS, in its sample project mflix, uses collection objects to do queries and updates. I am confused as such.

Comment: Oh in that to tutorial he/she has 2 database and what he/she did was create 2 client objects for the 2 databases he/she has. 1 for marketing and 1 for production, so he is maintaining 2 connection pools. Either you can do that or you can just maintain 1 pool and switch between databases.